# SQL - JOIN on a preferable value otherwise on a default one

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

- **watchlist**:

| media_id | saved_language |
| --- | --- |
| 000001 | en |
| 000002 | en |

- **media**:

| media_id | media_title | data_language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | Title in English | en |
| 000002 | Title in English | en |
| 000002 | Title in Italian | it |

I want to JOIN these two tables where the media_id is the same but the language must be a constant entered by me (es. "it") if available, otherwise it should use the default language saved in the watchlist table that will always be present.

The query I wrote is this :

```sql
SELECT * FROM watchlist
LEFT JOIN media 
   ON media.media_id = watchlist.media_id 
   AND (media.data_language = "it" OR media.data_language = watchlist.saved_language)
```

But using a simple OR I obviously get both languages as a result. I have already tried to use CASE too, but with the same result. What I want is to have back a single line for each media_id, where the language is preferably "it" or, only if it's not available in the media table, use the one saved in the watchlist table which will always have a match.

An example of the result I want:

| media_id | media_title | saved_language | data_language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | Title in English | en | en |
| 000002 | Title in Italian | en | it |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT w.*
FROM (SELECT wl.*, m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wl.media_id
                                ORDER BY (CASE m.data_language WHEN 'it' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM watchlist wl LEFT JOIN
           media m
           ON m.media_id = wl.media_id AND
              m.data_language IN ('it', wl.saved_language)
     ) w
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

However, if you just want the title, then two joins seems simpler:

```
select wl.*, coalesce(m_it.title, m_saved.title) as title
from watchlist wl left join
     media m_it
     on m_it.media_id = wl.media_id and
        m_it.language = 'it' left join
     media m_saved
     on m_saved.media_id = wl.media_id and
        m_saved.langauge = wl.saved_language;
```

Comment: Windows functions are a good choice if available.row_number and partition is an oracle only flavour I think.

Comment: @JensKrogsboell . . . Not at all.  Window functions have been part of the SQL standard for about 2 decades, I think.

Comment: Ok - that’s nice. I recommend your answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
SELECT *
FROM media m
WHERE m.data_language = ‘it’
UNION
SELECT *
FROM media m
JOIN watchlist w ON w.media_id = m.media_id
AND w.saved_language = m.data_language
WHERE m.media_id NOT IN (
    SELECT m2.media_id
    FROM media m2
    WHERE m2.data_language = ‘it’
  )
```